# How to globally stub component in vue test utils jest?

Tags: vue.js, jestjs, stub, testcase, vue-test-utils

I have registered a component globally and have used in multiple files.
There are more than 100 test cases files having both mount and shallowMount used, so i cannot go to each testcase and change mount to shallowMount.

Is there any way to stub component globally instead of going to each testcase and manually stubbing it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That's probably best done from a Jest [setup file](https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration#setupfiles-array) so that the stub is set for all tests:

```js
// jest.config.js
module.exports = {
  setupFiles: ['<rootDir>/jest.setup.js'],
}
```

In the setup file, you can stub components globally with Vue Test Utils' [`config.global.stubs`](https://test-utils.vuejs.org/api/#config-global):

```js
// jest.setup.js
import { config } from '@vue/test-utils'

// @vue/test-utils@v1
config.stubs['my-component'] = { template: '<div />' }

// @vue/test-utils@v2
config.global.stubs['my-component'] = { template: '<div />' }
```

Answer (score 3):

Stubs are now in `config.global.stubs`. It took me nearly three hours to find out.